# Double click on the whole row in gridview

Tags: wpf, datagridview, double-click

I want to click the whole row in my gridview and it will show me a dialog box. This dialog box contains values on my grid itself. Here is my sample xaml code..

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First Name" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Last Name" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Middle Name" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding MiddleName}"  />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Registration Day" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding RegistrationDay, StringFormat={}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDynamicHyperlinkColumn Header="Email" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Email}" />
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Password" Width="*" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Access}" />
```

those values are also the values in my dialog box. I just want to make double click with the row, instead of clicking the edit button that I implement.. Hope you can help me..

Answer (score 2):

two ways:

1. set gridview's `IsReadOnly = true` and than set gridview's MouseDoubleClick Event:

   ```
   private void dg1_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       Student s = dg1.SelectedItem as Student;
       if (s != null)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(s.Name + " " +  s.Age);
       }
   }
   ```
2. set gridview's PreviewMouseDoubleClick Event:

   ```
   private void dg1_PreviewMouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       Student s = dg1.SelectedItem as Student;
       if (s != null)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(s.Name + " " + s.Age);
       }

       e.Handled = true;
   }
   ```

Comment: <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdProducts" Grid.Row="2" MouseDoubleClick="grdProducts_MousedoubleClick" IsReadOnly="True">

is this correct? then on my code behind it should be like this..

private void grdProducts_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            
        }

tat mousedouble click should view my dialog box. Just like in my edit button code.. here:

Product product = (sender as RadButton).DataContext as Product;
            ShowProductWindow(product);

Sorry, I'm not that good in logic..

Comment: @Kim in this event , sender is RadGridView, so you can't use it like `sender as RadButton`. I dont know your logic, you want to show selecteditem?

Comment: For example, I already have data on every datacolumn header, and all those data will be in 1 row right when I save it? then i will double click that row on the grid and will show all the data on the grid to the dialog window. :)

Comment: show the selectedrow to a dialog? right?  try `Product p =  grdProducts.SelectedItem as Product`

Comment: Yes. that's what I mean.. But it doesnt work :(

Here is my code.. Correct me if Im wrong..

'private void grdProducts_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Product p = grdProducts.SelectedItem as Product;
        }'

and for the XAML:

 '<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="grdProducts" Grid.Row="2" IsReadOnly="True" MouseDoubleClick="grdProducts_MouseDoubleClick">'

Comment: I put a breakpoint on my method mouseclick, however, when i click rows on the grid, it doesnt show my dialogwindow. Heres what I did after the code you provided.  ShowProductWindow(product); The parameter product trigger an error.

Comment: grdProducts's itemsource is a List<Product>? add a breakpoint after `Product p =  grdProducts.SelectedItem as Product` , `p = null` ?

Comment: Yes, grdProducts is a list of products in the grid. the breakpoint goes to the ShowProductWindow(product) but still it the window does not show up.. `if{p != null}` is this what you mean?

Comment: ` private void grdProducts_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Product p = grdProducts.SelectedItem as Product;
            if (p != null)
            {
                ShowProductWindow(product);
            }
        }`

this..

Comment: @Kim `if{p != null}` is to see whether`grdProducts.SelectedItem as Product` is work or not. I can't debug it,so in this event, you need to get the row where your mouse pointed ,and then put the row's data to a new window.

Comment: how should I call the row or even the column where the mouse pointed in xaml for my code behind?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MVVM, you would probably prefer to attach an ICommand, which will be passed the DataContext of the row that has been clicked on, as a parameter.